# SQL Query Help - Total number of order qty per item from table

Tags: sql, sum

I have a many order table with 5 columns
ORDER_KEY, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_NUNBER, SHIP_WHSE, ORDER_QTY

I need to output just the total ORDER_QTY for each PRODUCT_NUMBER but my SQL-fu isn't strong enough to comprehend how to do a loop type iteration since this isn't just a sum of an entire column...

Comment: "SQL-fu" -- LOL

Comment: `select PRODUCT_NUMBER , sum(ORDER_QTY) from your_table group by PRODUCT_NUMBER`

Comment: `select PRODUCT_NUMBER, sum(ORDER_QTY) from orders group by PRODUCT_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.product_number,sum(t.order_qty)
from your_table t
group by t.product_number
```